# DOMPDF Wordpress nothing happens

Tags: php, wordpress, dompdf

I have a problem with DOMPDF integration into Wordpress.

Here are the steps done:

1. Installed [DOMPDF 0.6.1](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/tree/v0.6.1) 
   into the themedir/dompdf/
2. Created path /dompdf/lib/php-font-lib/classes where php lib is to be
   imported
3. Imported the "FontLib" folder contents
   ([version 0.4](https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib/releases)) into the
   /dompdf/lib/php-font-lib/classes

Here is the code:

```
    require_once(echo get_template_directory_uri()."/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

$html =
  '<html><body>'.
  '<p>Put your html here, or generate it with your favourite '.
  'templating system.</p>'.
  '</body></html>';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream(echo get_template_directory_uri()."/dompdf/testpdf.pdf");
```

Outputs nothing, I have also tried stream("testpdf.pdf"); as the last line but no success.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: why is there `echo` written *inside* a function call? remove it!

Comment: `echo` removed still doesn't work.

Comment: tried with absolute url within function also no success

Comment: dompdf 0.6.1 uses php-font-lib 0.3.x. You should copy the directory structure as it exists in the repository (though you can delete the "fonts" and "www" directories if you are trying to save space).

Comment: Also, the `stream()` method call should contain only the file name, e.g. `$dompdf->stream("testpdf.pdf");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
include get_template_directory() . '/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';

$html =
  '<html><body>'.
  '<p>Put your html here, or generate it with your favourite '.
  'templating system.</p>'.
  '</body></html>';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html( $html );
$dompdf->render();
file_put_contents( get_template_directory() . "/dompdf/testpdf.pdf");
```